# updating a dict causes problems

Tags: python

I'm trying to update the variable `students = {}`

```
    def addstudent(self, fname: str, lastname: str, age: int, bt: str, mother: str, father: str):

        students.update(f'("name": {fname}, "lastname": {lastname}, "age": {age}, "bloodtype": {bt}, "mother": {mother},'
                        f' "father": {father}), ')

        data = js.dumps(students)
        file = open('students.json', 'a')
        file.write(data)
        file.close()

    def removestudent(self, fname: str, lastname: str, age: int, bt: str, mother: str, father: str):
        students.pop(f'("name": {fname}, "lastname": {lastname}, "age": {age}, "bloodtype": {bt}, "mother": {mother}, '
                     f'"father": {father}), ')
        data = js.dumps(students)
        file = open('students.json', 'a')
        file.write(data)
        file.close()
```

i want to make it better and fix the current problem

```
students.update(f'("name": {fname}, "lastname": {lastname}, "age": {age}, "bloodtype": {bt}, "mother": {mother},'
```

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: `dict.update()` doesn't accept a string, and `pop()` doesn't either

Comment: And neither does `dict.pop()`

Comment: Why is `students` a dict? Shouldn't it be a list instead?

Comment: You are confusing f-string literals and dict displays: `students.update({"name": fname, "lastname": lastname, ...})`.

Comment: this is really strange code to walk through. may I ask where you got the suggestion for the `dict.update(f-string)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a *list of students* that you want to add or remove from, then use `students = []`. Then `append()` dictionaries to that, and `pop()` to remove the last...

By calling `update` on a dict, you only have one student, and update/override the same key-value pairs of one record.

If you want to "update" (or remove) a specific one, then you'd need to search through that list. And do `students[x] = {"name": ...}` (or `del students[x]`)

```
import json

students = []
filename = "students.json"

def update_file():
    global filename
    global students
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        json.dump(students, f)

def addstudent(fname: str, lastname: str, age: int, bt: str, mother: str, father: str):
    global students
    students.append({"name": fname, "lastname": lastname, "age": age, "bloodtype": bt, "mother": mother, "father": father})
    update_file()

def removestudent():
    global students
    students.pop()
    update_file()
```